# Get text using SendMessage() C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to get text from a textbox in a specific window. For this I'm using SendMessage Api function, I dont know if this is the corect way:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, 0, 0);
```

But I dont know how to print the text. For the argument 3 and 4 in msdn site it says: Additional message-specific information. So i dont know if I need to pass something else beside 0. I tried this also:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(text), LPARAM(text));
```

But it prints the name of the textbox, I need to retrieve the text inside the box?
How can I do this? Is SendMessage() the correct API function to use ?

Thank you.

edit:

I omit to say, I am enumerating the child windows from a window, and for me it looks like a textbox, where you have to type a name. I am retrieving the username of a Instant messaging window so I cant compare it to a string, is that a textbox ?

Comment: Textboxes don't have a name. You're trying to read something else.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: how can I test if a child window is a textbox ? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775460%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Still the same, I'm getting the textbox name, not what it is inside here

Comment: @vBx: Ok, wild guess here: by textbox name, I take it you mean the third parameter to CreateWindowEx (or equivalent)? That should in fact be the textbox contents - when you give a textbox a name, that's what it displays as its contents. Similarly, if you read its name, you are in fact reading its contents. If it's not doing that, there's something funny going on.

Comment: If the window has a caption defined, that is what `GetWindowText()` and `WM_GETTEXT` return.  Make sure you are specifying the `HWND` of the actual textbox itself, not its parent window.

Comment: Ok, i omit to say, I am enumerating the child windows from a window, and for me it looks like a textbox, where you have to type a name. I am retrieving the username of a Instant messaging window so I cant compare it to a string, is that a textbox ?

Comment: @vBx: you can use the [GetClassName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function to check if the `hwnd` you have is really a textbox. If it is, it should leave the string "EDIT" in the buffer you supply.

Comment: @Mac: i used Spy++ for that, and now GetClassName() too, but it says is "Static". What that does mean ?

Comment: @vBx: That means it is just a text label or image display, not a textbox. A STATIC control can only display information, and so the control you're looking at is *not* the username input textbox.

Comment: @Mac: oh yes, your right, i was getting the handle to the label. I guess the textboxes are the one with Edit...but how can I get a handle to them ? Thank you

Comment: If the textbox has an ID assigned to it (Spy++ can show that), then you can use `GetDlgItem()` to get its `HWND`, or just skip that and use `GetDlgItemText()` instead.  Otherwise, if you know the textbox's name (again, Spy++ can show that), then you can use `FindWindowEx()` instead.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - TeamB: i dont know where to look for the ID, there is COntrol ID, Process ID, Thread ID....witch one is it, if you know? I also tried to use GetCLassName and compare the text with "Edit" to see if it is a textbox, and then call GetWindowText for that textbos, but it doesnt print nothing, is this an incorect way ?

Comment: @vBx: from memory, you should compare to the string "EDIT" (note the upper-case), since IIRC windows standard control class names are all upper-case. Id say this is causing your comparison to fail, which is why nothing is happening. As for the ID, you want the control ID. Remy's right - that's probably the easier way.

Comment: @Mac: no, the comparasion is working good, cause i tested, its "Edit" but still doesnt work, as for the COntrol ID, its 000000D3, and i am getting an error with it, saying "invalid suffix "D3" on integer constant", how shoudl I pass this argument? Thanks

Comment: @vBx: the standard Edit control classname is "Edit".  Spy++ displays IDs in hexidecimal, so 000000D3 is hex for the integer value 211. If you want to hard-code a hex number in your code, you have to use the `0x` prefix, ie: `0x000000D3`.

Comment: I dont know why GetDlgItem returns NULL, i passed the parent window handle and the control ID, what could be the problem ?

Comment: Error no. is 1421: i guess is thsi one: ERROR_CONTROL_ID_NOT_FOUND'

Comment: OK, fix it, the textbox was inside another dialog box. Thanks you both

Answer (score 5):

Read the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632627.aspx) again.  It does NOT say "Additional message-specific information" for those parameters:

> wParam  The maximum number of
>   characters to be copied, including the
>   terminating null character.
>
> ANSI applications may have the string
>   in the buffer reduced in size (to a
>   minimum of half that of the wParam
>   value) due to conversion from ANSI to
>   Unicode.
>
> lParam  A pointer to the buffer that
>   is to receive the text.

Comment: Well i taked the documentation from the SendMessage() page, thats how it says there

Comment: Anyway so the corect version is the second one, but why I am getting the textbox name and not the text inside the textbox ?

Comment: `SendMessage()` is a general-purpose function, hense its documented parameters are arbitrary.  You need to look at the documentation for a particular message to know what the parameters represent.  As for your code, using `sizeof` like you are will only work correctly if you are sending the `WM_GETTEXT` message to an Ansi window and not a Unicode window.  Use `IsWindowUnicode()` to know whether to use an Ansi buffer or a Unicode buffer. As for why you are getting the textbox name, either you are sending the message to the wrong `HWND` to begin with, or the textbox has the `WS_CAPTION` style.

Comment: I was getting the handle of a label by mistake...but now I dont know how to get the handle of a textbox, do you know how can I test if a child window is a textbox ?

Answer (score 2):

This code works for local only:

```
char *szText;
szText = (char *)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, 255);
SendMessage(hEditControl, WM_GETTEXT, 255, (LPARAM)szText);
MessageBox(hWnd, szText, "It's your message", MB_OK | MB_TOPMOST);
GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)szText);
```